# Validacion con python a base de datos

Tags: python, mysql

estoy intentando hacer un IF que valide un dato que ingresa un usuario para saber si esta en la base de datos pero salta al ELSE directamente este o no

```
import mysql.connector

cnn_host = "localhost"
cnn_user = "root"
cnn_passwd = ""
cnn_database = "bot"

def mysql_verificacion(id_user):
    cnn = mysql.connector.connect(host=cnn_host, user=cnn_user, passwd=cnn_passwd, database=cnn_database)
    cur = cnn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM registros WHERE id = " + id_user)
    datos = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    cnn.close()
    return datos
```

**validacion**

```
 if mysql_verificacion(id) == id:
   
    print('MENU?')
 else:
    print('START')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que devuelve `fetchall()` es una `list()` con `tuple()` así que al momento de comparar esta comparando una `list` con un `id_user` que quiero suponer que es un `int`, en el caso de que no encuentre coincidencias devolverá una `list` vacía.

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que podrías hacer:

```
def mysql_verificacion(id_user):
   ...
   return datos[0] # retorna el primer elemento de la tupla.
```

Aunque te convendría usar `fetchone()` si quieres obtener solo un id.

También puedes modificar la función para que devuelva un valor boolea, `True` en caso exista y `False` en caso no exista algún dato coincidente con la consulta.

```py
def mysql_verificacion(id_user):
    ...
    return True if dato and dato[0] else False
```

Por lo tanto tu condición también se modificaría.

```py
if mysql_verificacion(id):
    print('MENU?')
 else:
    print('START')
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable como evito que salga este error?

Comment: asi coloque "return datos[0]" sigue saltando al else

Comment: Imprime lo que hay en la variable datos asi nos hacemos un idea

Comment: aparece asi

131<ID
(131,)<id en base de datos

Comment: imprime datos[0] así te devuelve solo el primer elemento

Comment: y usa `fetchone()`